# Three.js: Flickering Quads (not on same z plane)

Tags: three.js

I am working on a Three.js scene that renders some statically-positioned and textured quads, and some of my quads are flickering when I move my camera around. I've seen this in the past when two quads exist at the same x, y, z coords (I believe people refer to this as z-fighting).

I'm unsure what causes this behavior in cases where two quads don't intersect at all though:

[image]

Does anyone know what might cause this behavior, or how to remedy this behavior? I'd be grateful for any suggestions others can offer on this question.

P.S. My scene has ~2000 lines of JS right now, but I could spend the requisite hour making a demo of the problem if that's truly necessary.

Comment: I know you said they at different positions, but have you checked that the projection matrix you use doesn't lose depth information? If they have different positions in the world, but the vertex shader brings them to the same plane it would still result in Z fighting.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. How could I check that @florentteppe?

Comment: do you by any chance disable the `material.depthTest`?

Comment: As @gaitat said I would try to disable the depthtest, if there is always one 100% on top of the other without flickering then it's a depth issue. You can also use renderdoc to look at the output of the vertex shader.

Comment: Can you share the code where you initialize your camera? It may be that your near/far plane are *really* far apart, and you're losing depth precision. For example, if your camera is at 0.0001 near and 1000000 far, you might get z-fighting when objects come near each other without even touching. If this is the issue, you could try numbers that are closer together, like `0.1, 100`

Comment: I tried disabling the depth test, but that makes for a crazy M.C. Escher type scene where each quad's depth seems to change as the camera moves. I think @Marquizzo is on to something, as my camera initialization has gotten crazy: `var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.01, 1000000);`. I'm converting all of my coordinates now to a smaller domain...

Comment: If you're dealing with huge values you'll start running into floating point precision issues once objects get really far away. You could try setting the `logarithmicDepthBuffer` option to true to try to address the issue: `new WebGLRenderer({ logarithmicDepthBuffer: true })`.

Comment: @Marquizzo you nailed it, thanks very much! If you make your comment an answer with a little discussion to help others in the future I'll gladly accept it

Comment: @GarrettJohnson thanks for the idea. Translating my coordinates into a smaller domain 0:1000 works, but I'm glad to hear about the logarithmDepthBuffer. Also did you really get to go in a spacecraft and float around?

Comment: Ha, it was a parabolic flight so not quite a spacecraft but we did get some float time. Highly recommended. And yeah I've found enabling `logarithmDepthBuffer` to be extremely useful when you can't just scale down your near and far planes. Keep it in mind!

Comment: Your "far planes" he said, heh heh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with precision of the renderer's DepthBuffer. For instance, if you initialize your `PerspectiveCamera` with a [`.near`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.near) plane of 0.0001 and a [`.far`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.far) plane of 1000000, you could get z-fighting when objects come close to each other without even touching. To avoid this, you could try a smaller near-far range so your depth precision doesn't get "spread too thin", such as 0.1-100:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 0.1, 100 );
```